# How do I switch desktop session users from a shell script?

Tags: 12.04, unity, command-line, bash, scripts

I've got 2 users, `foo` and `bar`.  Currently if I'm logged in as `foo`, I can select `bar` from the menu in the top-right of Unity, and since `bar` has no password set, I switch straight to `bar`.  However, I want to have this same result when I run a shell script, rather than having to use the menu.  What do I need to put in the shell script to trigger the user switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
dm-tool switch-to-user username
```

where `username` is the username of the user you want to switch to.

Comment: +1. According to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=dm-tool, this is only available in 14.04

Comment: Thanks, although I'm using 12.04, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @glennjackman The manpage is only on 14.04, the program `dm-tool` is on 12.04 also. I just tried it on 12.04. It just doesn't have a manpage here, we have to use `dm-tool --help` for the options.